# Resetting an Inflated ListView's height, Listview height

Tags: android, android-listview, android-studio

I have a main activity and its layout is a scrollView and has a "linear layout" called [taskLayout].

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_jobs_view_single_holder);
final LinearLayout taskLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TaskLayout);
```

Then i'm inflating another view and adding the view to the main scrollviews.TaskLayout section.

```
LayoutInflater pickup_inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = pickup_inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_jobs_view_single_pickup,null);
taskLayout.addView(view);
```

the newly added view has a listView which used an

```
ADAPTER_PICKUP_PASSENGER extends BaseAdapter
```

where it loads data Asynchronously from an external database.

The main scrollview layout looks like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#0099cc">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/TaskLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
```

the Layout which contains listView looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@color/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ListView
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:id="@+id/lst_passenger_pickup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:minHeight="200dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </ListView>
```

Everything works fine except the listView's height is not WRAP_CONTENT it only shows one item. When i change the ListView's

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="200dp"
```

then the ListView gets 200dp height. For some reasons android:minHeight does not have any effect.

Ideally i would want to set the hight as WRAP_CONTENT so all items could be viewed but it doesn't work but either WRAP_CONTENT or FILL_PARENT just shows one item and setting manual height as 200dp is sometime too big if the list has only one item.

I have tried following steps so far:

1. In the Adapter just before returning convertView, i tried to do parent.requestLayout();
2. After setting the adapter to the listview, listview.requestLayout()

Nothing happens. could anyone shed some light please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will expand your listview as per your row height and width dynamically.

```
public static void getTotalHeightofListView(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter mAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

    int totalHeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View mView = mAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

        mView.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),

                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        totalHeight += mView.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (mAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: where would I put/call this function? after onPostExecution of the adapter?

Comment: yes after binding adapter , call this and pass listview object

Comment: down-vote for not explaning & only posting wall of code

Comment: That person need help and its helpful to him

Comment: yes it works thank you for the help. I would have been happier if you explain why it didn't work initially.

Comment: In this code it will take height and width of a row and calculate it dynamically.  In first stage you only able to see one record cause it only expand for only one row . By this code it will expand as per your number of record * size of record